# Return type of out-of-line definition of a constructor differs from that in the declaration

Tags: c++, constructor, return-type

I am having an issue regarding a derived class constructor.

Here's my class  `LeftV`,

```
class LeftV : public Body{
public:
    LeftV(string o, string name, int mag, string dir, char type);
    
};
```

and the implementation,

```
LeftV::LeftV(string o, string name, int mag, string dir, char type) : Body(o, name, mag, dir){
    this->type = type;
    
};
```

I get the following error,

"Return type of out-of-line definition of 'LeftV::LeftV' differs from that in the declaration."

Why is it telling me the return type is different if its a constructor I'm declaring?

Thanks!

Comment: `LeftV` doesn't have a member named `type`.

Comment: After adding missing pieces, the code shown [compiles without error](https://godbolt.org/z/4TM3sT65d). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code not shown. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].